# Can you create a centralized topic in ZeroMQ?

Tags: c#, php, .net, zeromq

I would really like to try ZeroMQ and I am wondering whether my problem can be solved using it.

THE PROBLEM: I have multiple subscribers and multiple publishers. In a centralized broker architecture the publishers would publish a message to a topic (kind of like multicast address) and the subscribers would get the messages from the topic and act on the messages. I can't use Multicast because our network topology has multiple subnets and IT guys will not forward my multicast packets to all subnets.

Since there is no centralized broker, how can this problem be solved in ZeroMQ? (sample code would be great in any language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was doing a bit of reading. And this is possible in ZeroMQ after all. You would use a "FORWARDER" device as:

[image: Instructions]

```
import zmq

def main():

    try:
        context = zmq.Context(1)
        # Socket facing clients
        frontend = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
        frontend.bind("tcp://*:5559")

        frontend.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")

        # Socket facing services
        backend = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
        backend.bind("tcp://*:5560")

        zmq.device(zmq.FORWARDER, frontend, backend)
    except Exception, e:
        print e
        print "bringing down zmq device"
    finally:
        pass
        frontend.close()
        backend.close()
        context.term()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This is a version of a "broker" (scaled down to fit the purpose), and is what I was referring to in the third option in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very bare-bones question, but I'll attempt to give you some guidance... just understand you haven't described an actual problem, just a use-case that has several potential solutions depending on your particular needs.

At a very basic level, you can just have every subscriber maintain a list of every publisher, and subscribe to each one directly.  This is all very brute force and manual, but that's step one to accomplishing what you want.

If maintaining that list becomes an intractable problem for each node, you create a new node to manage the list of subscribers for you.  When a publisher spins up, it provides notice of itself to the manager node, which informs subscribers that they need to subscribe to it.

If we're talking a truly large number of publishers and subscribers and a full net topology is begging for issues, you can write your own broker to subscribe to each publisher, and then republish to all subscribers.

There are nuances with each of these solutions, but at a high level these are your three basic choices.  If you have some sense of which best fits your situation and you need further guidance, please add some more details and we can get into specifics.

Comment: Jason, exactly what I was looking for! Just wanted to get an idea of how this can be accomplished in ZeroMQ and whether it would be something suitable for this MQ. Sounds like it is back to RabbitMQ for me.

Comment: @Denis, ZMQ is really more of a messaging library than a full, out of the box messaging system.  RabbitMQ and it's ilk have fully fleshed out how it handles various communication paradigms, where ZMQ leaves the strategy up to you.  It can be very powerful when the standard solutions (RabbitMQ) don't quite fit what you're after, or have too much overhead in one area and not enough in another... but it means you have to be protocol designer in addition to implementer.  If AMQP works for you (it was designed by the same people as ZMQ, by the way), then it's probably the right choice.